# Why can't I convert a vector into a matrix with 'as.matrix' function?

Tags: r

```
> tem = 1:9801
> dim(as.matrix(tem,nrow=99,ncol=99))
[1] 9801    1
> dim(matrix(tem,nrow=99,ncol=99))
[1] 99 99
```

I believe that 'as.matrix' function can convert a vector into a matrix with pre-specified numbers of rows and columns.
But as you see in the above R result, 'as.matrix' function does not, but 'matrix' function does. 
Why doesn't 'as.matrix' function work as it is supposed to be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's the way `as.matrix` works.  It does its best to convert the input data into a matrix keeping things as close to possible.  In this case turning a vector into a single column matrix makes the most sense.  If you look at the implementation (found in `as.matrix.default`) you'll see it ignores all input except the first (in this case the input vector) and just makes a single column matrix always.

If you want to specify the number of rows and columns what is wrong with using `matrix`?